# System BOOT fail

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

My PC started behaving weird when booting. When I press the power button it sits about 25sec doing nothing, just spinning the fans like crazy. After that it beeps as normal, starts checks and this happens:

[image: Your system last boot fail or POST interrupted]

When I press F1 it boots correctly and everything works.

I tried clearing CMOS, replacing motherboard battery (old one was very old), restoring default settings, nothing helped.

It started doing it after I swapped HDD (but happens even when it's taken out) and replaced graphics card with a very similar model (I don't really have the option to put the old one back).

My config:
Asus M2N-E, AMD Athlon X2 5000+, AMD Radeon HD 5450, 4gb ram, No floppy or DVD drives.

Any help would be appreciated :-)

[EDIT]

I put back the previous card (Radeon HD 6450) and everything seems to work. So now I know what's causing it, but I need that card in another pc :-(

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Mu question is - how to make my PC boot properly with the new graphics card (Radeon 5450).

Comment: You have verified the card is good in another pc?

Comment: Yes, both cards work well in the other pc without issues.

Comment: What are the differences between he two machines?

Comment: The other machine: CPU: AMD Athlon II X2 260, Motherboard: Asus M5A78L-M LX, 4GB Kingston Ram, LG DVD. Fairly similar, a bit newer.